# How to declare/export ShellDispatcher in Controller cakephp 2?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I was following this article https://medium.com/@narendravaghela/cakephp-execute-shell-command-from-controller-90c8323558a and get stuck with ShellDispatcher that can't be found.

```
<?php
//namespace App\Controller;
 
//use App\Controller\AppController;
//use Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher;
 
class ExampleController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $shell = new ShellDispatcher();
        $output = $shell->run(['cake', 'foo']);
 
        if (0 === $output) {
            $this->Flash->success('Success from shell command.');
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('Failure from shell command.');
        }
 
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Understand your question about committed first three lines:) But in that case each of them can be found as well.
My ShellDispatcher.php is in `lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher` but this `use lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher;` also gives me an error "not found".
What I am doing wrong?

I tried do like this `App::uses('ShellDispatcher', 'Console');` as I have in my code, but got this error `Fatal error: Cannot declare class App, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 65`

Comment: Looks like you have some fundamental misunderstandings of how PHP namespaces work. I'd suggest that you read up on that a little bit, otherwise you're just going to be shooting in the dark and hoping to hit the right magic combination.

Comment: Thanks for advice Greg. I think I don't need here namespace at all ... why then the problem with getting `ShellDispatcher`?

Comment: The article you are referencing is for CakePHP3, you better look for something specific to CakePHP 2. CakePHP 2 doesn't use namespaces, so `App::uses()` would be the right call here.